# Why I am getting array JSON response when I call method from Web API?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, asp.net-web-api, postman

I am getting array which include my JSON when I call that method in postman like

```
 [
    {
        "spark_version": "7.6.x-scala2.12"
    }
]
```

**API Method**

```
[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetTest(int ActivityId)
    {
        string StoredJson = "exec sp_GetJobJSONTest " +
            "@ActivityId = " + ActivityId ;
        var result =  _context.Test.FromSqlRaw(StoredJson);
        return Ok(result);
    }
```

I want to get rid from square brackets [ ] in my response. How should I do that ?

Comment: Your stored procedure probably returns a resultset containing of a single row. Thus, the `result` you are returning will be some sort of List/Array/..., thus it will be converted to a  JSON array. If you only want to return the first element of it, you have to get out the first element from result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for getting first row need to use `.FirstOrDefault()`

```
[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetTest(int ActivityId)
    {
        string StoredJson = "exec sp_GetJobJSONTest " +
            "@ActivityId = " + ActivityId ;
        var result =  _context.Test.FromSqlRaw(StoredJson).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
        return Ok(new {details = result };);
    }
```

Comment: I am getting this error then :System.InvalidOperationException: ''FromSqlRaw' or 'FromSqlInterpolated' was called with non-composable SQL and with a query composing over it. Consider calling 'AsEnumerable' after the method to perform the composition on the client side

Comment: @blac040
 try `var result =  _context.Test.FromSqlRaw(StoredJson).ToList().FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: @blac040 is it working?

Comment: And can you please help me once more. Now I want to save that string '7.6.x.scala2.12' into another variable and show that as response. How can i do that ?

Comment: try  `var sparkVersion=  _context.Test.FromSqlRaw(StoredJson).ToList().FirstOrDefault()["spark_version"];`  do you want like this?

Comment: If I explain more like { "details" : " {JSON}" } this is response I have now. I have JSON as string in details. I want to save that JSON into another variable and show only that JSON in response.

Comment: I hope you understand my question

Comment: @blac040 I have updated my answer. please check if any issues let me know.

Comment: Yes, It is working the way I want. Thanks again

Comment: I am new in .Net. If In future, I need some assistance. Can you please help me ?

Comment: @blac040 ok i will try but I am not available all time